# Python combine two ndarrays

Tags: python

What's the most pythonic way to combine two numpy arrays, such that each array

```
(x,y,z) and (x1,y2,z3)
```

combined to

```
(2,x,y,z)
```

where the two lists are stacked? Is it np.stack?

EDIT: To clarify, both arrays are still there such that,

```
np.array([x,y,z],
         [x1,y2,z2])
```

So when indexing onto the first element, you get the first tuple. The second element gets the second tuple.

Comment: where did the 2 in output come from? can you check your example output? Please provide an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with actual numpy arrays.

Comment: why there is not a single element from 2nd array in output array?

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar check example, clearer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just use `np.stack` and it works as you wanted!
for example:

```
x = np.arange(100).reshape(5, 2, 10) 
x.shape # 5x2x10
np.stack((x, x)).shape # become 2x5x2x10
```

It concatenates its input along new axis created in front.
But if you have lots of arrays wanted to be concatenate I suggest you to convert them to lists and then do concatenates and again convert the result to numpy array, it's way faster.